# Use googleVis in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, googlevis

I am in the process to develop a shiny app to give users the ability to select timeline plot for different variables. For illustration, I would like to use the following data:

```
datTL <- data.frame(Position=c(rep("President", 3), rep("Vice", 3)),
                    Name=c("Washington", "Adams", "Jefferson",
                           "Adams", "Jefferson", "Burr"),
                    start=as.Date(x=rep(c("1789-03-29", "1797-02-03", 
                                          "1801-02-03"),2)),
                    end=as.Date(x=rep(c("1797-02-03", "1801-02-03", 
                                        "1809-02-03"),2)))
```

Here is what I have managed to come up with:

```
#ui.R
library(shiny)
library(googleVis)
shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  selectInput('id','select a name',choices = as.character(unique(datTL$Name))),
  htmlOutput('timeline')
))

#server.R
shinyServer(function(input,output){
  datainput=reactive({daTL[daTL$Name==input$id,]})
  output$timeline=renderGvis({gvisTimeline(data=datTL,
                          rowlabel="Name",
                          barlabel="Position",
                          start="start",
                          end="end")})
})
```

With my code, I can create an app with a dropdown list including the names of presidents and a timeline plot for all president. What I am struggling with is to use link the dropdown list with the timeline plot so an user can filter the plot by selecting names from the list. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working server code. There was some typo in your code, also reactives are used as `datainput()`.

```
shinyServer(function(input,output){
    datainput=reactive({datTL[datTL$Name==input$id,]})
    output$timeline=renderGvis({
        gvisTimeline(data=datainput(),
                                             rowlabel="Name",
                                             barlabel="Position",
                                             start="start",
                                             end="end")})
})
```

Comment: Hi @warmoverflow, thanks for your answer. I am just wondering is it possible to wrap the `datainput` function into the `renderGivs` function?

Comment: Should work. Just remove `reactive`. It wouldn't be a function though, just a variable.